# Grouping by prices and summing their sales into a specific price range using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a following code to group my sales into specific price range like following:

```
var priceRanges = ranges.Select(r => new PriceRangeGraph
{
    Price = Math.Round(r, 2),
    Sales = lista.Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.SalePrice) == r)
                 .Sum(x => x.SaleNumber)    
}).ToList();
```

Please note following line of code:

```
Sales = lista.Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.SalePrice) == r)
             .Sum(x => x.SaleNumber)
```

And assuming my range is a List typed of value - double whose values are:

```
Item 0: 0 
Item 1: 3.57
Item 2: 7.14
Item 3: 10.70
Item 4: 14.28
Item 5: 17.84
Item 6: 21.41
Item 7: 24.99
```

And in entire list there are 2 sales whos' sale price is 15 ($);

Doing this query like above places the price sale into 17.84 range because 14.28$ is < 15$ , thus this query doesn't do it's job as it should. My question is, is there a more intelligent way to solve this issue, placing the sales into the really corresponding ranges?

Can someone help me out to rewrite this ?

P.S. Maybe it's indeed placed in the right range... But how would i display these ranges, I mean in which order?

```
Some would have to be list[i-1] - [list[i]
```

If I'm correct?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I don't either :) Are you asking **us** what should be the **desired** output of **your** query??

Comment: What do you mean by 'ranges'? Are you trying to group the sum of `Sales` so that a for a range of `$14.28` to `$17.84` the result would be 2 if there are 2 sales of `$15.00`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: And what is `SaleNumber` (is that something indicating the quantity of the item that was sold for a specific sale?). It would be a lot clearer if you could show a sample of some records, and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes it specifies sale amount for a specific transaction =) .. Well it turns out this works quite nice actually. I was just representing the ranges on graph wrongly xD

Answer (score 0):

You Can reverse your ranges and then find firstOrDefault(y=>y<=x.SalePrice). And later order your PriceRanges by its Price.

Sorry this answer is typed from iPad so it's not Well formatted.